# Google Analytics Cross Domain tracking with authentication and a gateway page in between

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-tag-manager

Case:
We have a Landing page (lets call it mypage.com) with CTA button "Start your trial" when you click it you are redirected to identify.mypage.com and again to auth.mypage.com where you sign up using email/google or other identification methods. After the sign up you are directed to parent.mypage.com where the registration event is sent to Google Analytics.

For reasons we can't implement the gtag in the auth or identify page. So we need to somehow enable cross domain tracking with these two pages in between.

Currently we are not able to send UTM parameters to the parent-page where the registration event is sent to GA so we are not able to see the source of the Goal.

What can I do to get the cross domain tracking working properly, or is it even possible with the current setup?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, the current flow is:

mypage.com -> identify.mypage.com -> auth.mypage.com -> parent.mypage.com

I think what you need to do here is to have mypage.com and parent.mypage.com be on the same analytics property.

Then in the property settings, add identify.mypage.com and auth.mypage.com as referral exclusions. This way the acquisition data for when they land on mypage.com should stay when they're sent back to parent.mypage.com after authenticating.

Answer (score 0):

Your pages are located on subdomains of one high level domain, so cross-domain tracking in GA works automatically in this case, no additional configuration is required. Just use one GA tracker for all pages you can and session will be uninterrupted.

See google support (for analytycs.js, but gtag.js works the same way):
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034148?hl=en#Subdomains